# How to request if some of the package is out of date

Tags: server, package-management, software-updater

Ubuntu is famous for it's updated software package, but sometimes the package is out of date.

For eg:http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=zabbix-server-mysql, the version is 1.8.x which is release at 2011. Now they have a new version and I want to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the link you asked about, there are newer versions available on Ubuntu 12.10 and 13.04, respectively. You will need to build your own packages, install from source, or request a [backport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBackports) of the package.